# Where to find libImgFun?

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, android

I have to update libpng in application because of [security vulnerability](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127?hl=en).

There is no source code, but I do have APK and a keystore for the app.

Libpng is not used directly, I've decompiled APK and looked what libraries are using libpng. There are two – OpenCV and libImgFun (*.so files).

I've managed to update OpenCV. I've compiled the library, get .so files, replace them in the application, compile, sign and it seems to work.

But I can't find out what is libImgFun and where to find it. I was looking in ndk and openCV folders with no success.

Where to get it? Is it possible to replace .so files in that way?

Comment: Sorry to say but ImgFun seems to be the NDK source of the app, I mean to say that it is not an Open Source Project, rather it is  the proprietary code used by the app itself.

Comment: @ZdaR you mean it's like a hand-written library, right? But there are so many mentions in a Google while searching "libImgFun.so". Doesn't seem to be a common way to name things.